# XML Deserialization C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize an XML file into an object in the Program file of my Windows Forms application as below:

```cs
            List<UserAccessGroup> AccessGroups = new List<UserAccessGroup>();

            AccessGroups = SerializerHelper.DeSerializeObject<List<UserAccessGroup>>(@"C:\Users\Michael"
            + @"\Google Drive\FDM Dev Course Content\Workspace\SystemAdmin\SystemAdmin\"
            + @"XML Data Store\UserAccessGroups.xml");

            UserAccessGroup SystemAdmin_App = new UserAccessGroup();

            foreach (UserAccessGroup group in AccessGroups)
            {
                if (group.Name.Equals("Admin Operators"))
                {
                    SystemAdmin_App = group;
                }
            }
```

When I run this code, I am getting an unhandled exception in my foreach loop, stating that Access Groups is null.

However, when I copy and paste this snippet of code into a blank console application, it runs fine and when I check AccessGroups with a break point, it has 4 members, as expected.

Can anyone please tell me why deserialization is not working in my program file?

Also, here is my XML file:

```cs
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfUserAccessGroup xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <UserAccessGroup>
    <Name>Admin Operators</Name>
    <Access_Group>
      <int>999</int>
    </Access_Group>
  </UserAccessGroup>
  <UserAccessGroup>
    <Name>Shareholders</Name>
    <Access_Group />
  </UserAccessGroup>
  <UserAccessGroup>
    <Name>Brokers</Name>
    <Access_Group />
  </UserAccessGroup>
  <UserAccessGroup>
    <Name>StockExMgrs</Name>
    <Access_Group />
  </UserAccessGroup>
</ArrayOfUserAccessGroup>
```

EDIT: forgot to include the SerializerHelper class that I am using for serialization/deserialization, please see below:

```cs
    public static class SerializerHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes an object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="serializableObject"></param>
        /// <param name="fileName"></param>

        private static readonly log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(
            "SerializerHelper.cs");

        public static void SerializeObject<T>(string filepath, T serializableObject)
        {
            if (serializableObject == null) { return; }

            try
            {
                XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializableObject.GetType());
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(stream, serializableObject);
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    xmlDocument.Load(stream);
                    xmlDocument.Save(filepath);
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log exception here
                logger.Error("Error Serializing: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes an xml file into an object list
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="fileName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static T DeSerializeObject<T>(string filepath)
        {
            T objectOut = default(T);

            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filepath)) return objectOut;

            try
            {
                string attributeXml = string.Empty;

                XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDocument.Load(filepath);
                string xmlString = xmlDocument.OuterXml;

                using (StringReader read = new StringReader(xmlString))
                {
                    Type outType = typeof(T);

                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(outType);
                    using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(read))
                    {
                        objectOut = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                        reader.Close();
                    }

                    read.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log exception here
                logger.Error("Error Deserializing: " + ex.Message);
            }

            return objectOut;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: UserAccessGroup class below:

```cs
    [Serializable]
    public class UserAccessGroup : IUserAccessGroup
    {
        private String name;

        private List<int> AccessGroup = new List<int>();

        public String Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public List<int> Access_Group
        {
            get { return AccessGroup; }
            set { AccessGroup = value; }
        }

        public UserAccessGroup()
        {
        }

        public UserAccessGroup(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public List<int> getUserIDs()
        {
            return AccessGroup;
        }

        public void removeUser(int userID)
        {
            AccessGroup.Remove(userID);
            return;
        }

        public void addUser(int userID)
        {
            AccessGroup.Add(userID);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show us UserAccessGroup model?

Comment: Sure, I will post it up in an edit now

Comment: Is your User Acces group Serializable?

Comment: are you running both programs as the same user?

Comment: @user3801869 xmlserializer doesn't care whether your type is marked as serializable

Comment: @MichaelHennigan but I asked about UserAccessGroup model but not helper

Comment: Yes, UserAccessGroup is serializable, it's posted now. @ajg What do you mean running both programs as the same user?

Comment: my guess would be that the first program does not have access to the xml file. This would be caused by a permissions (i.e. user) issue. Marc's answer covers it i think.

Comment: @MegaTron again: `XmlSerializer` *doesn't care* about `[Serializable]`; also: the default for elements in arrays /lists *is already* their name.

Comment: So this is the line from my log file: "22:23:22,493 [1] ERROR SerializerHelper.cs - Error Deserializing: Configuration system failed to initialize"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem can be summarized as:

```
T objectOut = default(T);

if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filepath)) return objectOut;

try
{
    // ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Log exception here
    logger.Error("Error Deserializing: " + ex.Message);
}

return objectOut;
```

(note that `default(T)` for `T=List<UserAccessGroup>` is `null`)

So: for `AccessGroups` to be `null`, one of 2 things is happening:

- the file does not exist (so the code is exiting near the top)
- an exception is being thrown

Check each of these. If the first: add it. If the second: read the `.Message`, and the `.InnerException.Message` etc (`XmlSerializer` is very big on inner-exceptions)

`XmlSerializer` will not return `null` for the root object of a list / array, so: it is one of those two things.

Put a breakpoint on the not-exists `return`, and in the `catch`, and you should find what is happening. Alternatively, look at where-ever `logger` writes. Maybe also add something that writes to `logger` when the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer @Marc Gravell! The file definitely does exist so it must be an exception. I can't edit or run the code right now as I am in work but I will try find the exception when I'm back home and post up how I get on.

Comment: So this is the line from my log file: "22:23:22,493 [1] ERROR SerializerHelper.cs - Error Deserializing: Configuration system failed to initialize"

Comment: @MichaelHennigan that usually means there's an error in your config file - often related to custom sections being used that haven't been properly defined / announced. Try nuking your config file (web.config / app.config / etc); if that fixes it: add pieces back until it breaks again

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It is the config file. I just ran the code again logging the inner exception and got this line in my log file: "22/06/2017 20:56 [1] ERROR SerializerHelper.cs - Error Deserializing: Only one <configSections> element allowed per config file and if present must be the first child of the root <configuration> element. (C:\Users\Michael\Google Drive\FDM Dev Course Content\Workspace\SystemAdmin\SystemAdmin\bin\Debug\SystemAdmin.exe.Config line 6)"

Comment: @MichaelHennigan \o/ there we go; hopefully you should be all set now, then

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: "Error Deserializing: Cannot serialize interface SystemAdmin.IUserIDGenerator." Should I only be serializing/deserializing concrete implementations rather than their interfaces?

Comment: Okay, never mind. I fixed that issue too now. It's FINALLY working! Thanks so much for all the help, I really appreciate it!